# Inject Local img on friend's site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So basically my friend has asked me to make a few changes to his companies site landing page. I am trying to make a mock up for him but cant replace an image with a local image on my comp in Firefox inspect element. I keep getting "Could not load image".

I have tried changing just the html code in inspect element, as well as first removing it and then injecting it as a javascript variable into the parent element with .innerHTML

anyone have any way to get this to work.

Comment: You can't inject images onto a web site from your local machine...This would be a really bad security flaw

Comment: Set up a local web server and put the images on it, so you can just change the source of the site in firebug, and replace one of the images with one from your local host.

Comment: @Liam, I believe OP just chose their wording wrong. It looks as though OP is trying to manipulate the elements through the Elements pane of the dev tools, not trying to an actual cross site injection. For instance, change the `src` attribute to point to a `file:///` path. dvitt90, are you sure you are using a valid url? If the image is local you would need to use a `file:///` url ie `file:///C/Users/Me/someimage.jpg`

Comment: ^ bingo. i did not say a dam thing about cross site scripting.

Comment: Copy the site itself locally and edit it there. As @NickR says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to setup a local web server, you can view-source on his page, save it local as newpage.html, download all of the assets you need (.css, .js, images) then implement whatever new local images/content you have.

You can then share he new screen grab.

Answer (score 2):

As Liam said, you cannot do what you are asking.  Instead, just copy the source code from your friends landing page and change all the image href's to a local directory on your machine.

Comment: You can get the css from their server, just look in the HTML source and find where the css is stored and download it.